# Removing <script> tags using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I'm filtering through a string (Pulled from a text file), and removing all  and  tags using preg_replace. For some reason, it is removing the actual text "script", but leaving the <> and . I've tried subbing in /< (to try and treat it as a literal), but that just generates errors. How do I get it to remove the brackets as well? The input is `<script>Text</script>`
Here's the code:

```
$file = file_get_contents($directory . "original-" . $name);
$file = htmlentities($file);
$file = preg_replace('<script>', '', $file);
$file = preg_replace('<\script>', '', $file);
```

And here is the output:

```
  <>TEXT</>
```

Comment: You are missing delimeters and escapes and `htmlentities` is changeing your string it might not contain what you expect

Comment: Could you show me how it should look? Really new to regular expressions.

Comment: @mattegener Just place the `htmlentities` line after the replacement of script tags. Also its forward slash `/` not \ backslash

Comment: @RahilWazir I tried that, but same result as my previous attempts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

```
$html = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $html);
```

But you might want to have a look at the `strip_tags` function

Comment: Although this is the reason why, you simply state `The answer it <this>`. You don't explain *why* it is the answer.

Comment: because 1.  this has been explained a million times on this website and this question is coming up every other day.   2.  this should most likely not be solved with regexp, and strip_tags should be used instead.

Comment: A single line saying `PHP suports multi delimiters and the chars < > are a ser of delimiters supported.` would be enough. You won't die and you will have a better answer.

Answer (score 4):

The pattern you use in your `preg_*` functions has to have some kind of a [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) before and after that. PHP allows many different delimiters, so it's treating your angle brackets as the regexp delimiter, and not part of the pattern. I ordinarily use `{` and `}` as delimiters, many other people use slashes, hash signs, square brackets, parentheses. Angle brackets are also permitted as delimiters, that's why your pattern fails.

You can solve this by adding some delimiters around your patterns, e.g.:

```
$file = preg_replace('/<script>/', '', $file);
```

Also, note that PHP regular expressions are case sensitive, so your pattern is foiled by a tag that says `<SCRIPT>` or `<Script>`. The `i` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) after the pattern (after the closing delimiter) makes it case insensitive (`/<script>/i`). Also, there are many different ways to write HTML tags that are still interpreted by the browser, e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
<script src="..." />
```

On a sidenote, and maybe I'm reading too much into your question, you should not, I repeat, [not use regexps to parse HTML, and especially to sanitize it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Without code examples, your answer is quite incomplete. But I agree with the last line. Completely!

Answer (score 0):

$html = preg_replace('#(.*?)#is', '', $html);