# How to remove scripts tags inside another code by regex

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to remove script tags from the source code using regular expression.

```
/<\s*script[^>]*[^\/]>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*script\s*>/is
```

But I ran into the problem when I need to remove the code inside another code.

[Please see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmP6k.png)

I'm tested in `https://regex101.com/r/R6XaUT/1`

How do I correctly create a regular expression so that it can cover all the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255873/removing-script-tags-using-preg-replace

Answer (score 1):

**Sample text:**

```
$text = '<b>sample</b> text with <div>tags</div>';
```

**Result for strip_tags($text):**

```
Output: sample text with tags
```

**Result for strip_tags_content($text):**

```
Output: text with
```

**Result for strip_tags_content($text, ''):**

```
Output: <b>sample</b> text with
```

**Result for strip_tags_content($text, '', TRUE);**

```
Output: text with <div>tags</div>
```

I hope that someone is useful :)
[source link](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the PHP function strip_tags. See

http://php.net/manual/de/function.strip-tags.php

```
$string = "<div>hello</div>";
echo strip_tags($string);
```

Will output

```
hello
```

You also can provide a list of tags to keep.

==

Another approach is this:

```
// Load a file into $html
$html = file_get_contents('scratch.html');
$matches = [];
preg_match_all("/<\/*([^\s>]*)>/", $html, $matches);

// Have a list of all Tags only once
$tags = array_unique($matches[1]);

// Find the script index and remove it
$scriptTagIndex = array_search("script", $tags);
if($scriptTagIndex !== false) unset($tags[$scriptTagIndex]);

// Taglist must be a string containing <tagname1><tagename2>...
$allowedTags = array_map(function ($s) { return "<$s>"; }, $tags);

// Stript the HTML and keep all Tags except for removed ones (script)
$noScript = strip_tags($html,join("", $allowedTags));

echo $noScript;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to clear only the script tags, the exclude list will be very large.

Comment: Do you also want the contents in between the script tags to be removed?

Comment: @AlexKovalev Why only the script tags? If it is security you are concerned about you need to realize that you can run javascript from html tag attributes like `onLoad` so you gain nothing by removing just the script tags.

Comment: @jeroen This isn't for security, this code prevents the DOM parser. class DOMDocument сan't parse the document unless you clear the scripts.

Comment: @AlexKovalev Really? Maybe here you can find a better parser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029341/dom-parser-that-allows-html5-style-in-script-tag. And you might want to add that to your question, perhaps it will attract answers in a different direction.

Comment: I've added another approach. it may look somewhat overkill, but is nice and safe IMHO.